# scalatags TypedTag from HTMLElement

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalatags

Is it possible to create `TypedTag` from `HTMLElement` in [scalatags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags)?

Building `HTMLElement` from `TypedTag` is straightforward:

```
import scalatags.JsDom.all._

val typedTag: TypedTag[Div] = div("abc")
val d: Div = typedTag.render
//somwhere `type Div = raw.HTMLDivElement`
```

Is it possible to create conversion in opposit direction? 
Given instance of `Div` I want `TypedTag[Div]` in order to manipulate it using scalatags goodies and then render it back to `HTMLElement`. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no -- that doesn't actually make any sense if you think it through, at least not that way. The thing is, a `TypedTag` isn't an HTML element, it's something that *builds* an HTML element. By contrast, the `HTMLElement` is an actual element. So basically, you're trying to get a bag of cocoa powder from an already-mixed cup.

I suspect it would be possible to build what you're asking for, but it would be a bit involved -- you'd have to build something that takes an `HTMLElement` and maps back to a `TypedTag` parameterized for that element type, then work with the `TypedTag`, render it and *replace* the existing `HTMLElement` in-page. It could be done, but I suspect it's more work than it's worth...